# Is there any functionality through which I can get the url of a reply message in msteams's Team whose conversation is initiated by user

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, botframework, microsoft-teams

There's a scenario in which I want to get the url of reply message in a msteams's team whose conversation is initiated by user. With graph api, I'm getting the original message but not the reply id of that message due to which I can't get the replies of that original message. I am getting the replies of message when the conversation is initiated by a Bot in a team but not when the conversation is initiated by user. Is there any way possible throgh which I can also get the reply message of the original message when conversation gets initiated by a user ?.I am using this `/teams/{teamId}/channels/{channelId}/messages` graph api to get messages and this `/teams/${teamId}/channels/${channelId}/messages/${messageid}/replies/{replyToId}` graph api to get the reply of any message.

Comment: You an get replies of the original message by using [List Message Replies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-list-messagereplies?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http).In response the you will receive the Id that is the actual Id of that reply. And reply to Id is the Id of original message. You can get details of a specific reply by passing the Id.